# How to make round cornered NSTableView rows?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, row, nstableview

I'd like to make something like this (on the new iTunes):
[image]

As you can see when the row is selected it's "highlight" state is a round cornered row.
How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subclass `NSTableview` and override `-highlightSelectionInClipRect:` method.

It can be done like this:

Change your tableView's highlighting mode from regular to **Source list** in **Attributes Inspector**:

[image: Change highlight mode image]

And now subclass `NSTableView` like this:

```
-(void)highlightSelectionInClipRect:(NSRect)theClipRect
{
    NSRange visibleRowIndexes = [self rowsInRect:theClipRect];
    NSIndexSet *selectedRowIndexes = [self selectedRowIndexes];
    NSUInteger endRow = visibleRowIndexes.location + visibleRowIndexes.length;
    NSUInteger row;

    for (row=visibleRowIndexes.location; row<endRow; row++)
    {
        if([selectedRowIndexes containsIndex:row])
        {
            NSRect rowRect = NSInsetRect([self rectOfRow:row], 3, 4);
            NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rowRect xRadius:4.0 yRadius:4.0];
            [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.474 green:0.588 blue:0.743 alpha:1] set];
            [path fill];
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's not working for my tableview view based. I've tested it with a cell based and it works fine. How to do that on a view based tableview?

Comment: @PedroVieira for view based tableView take a look at Apple's example **HoverTableDemo** (this example should answer your question): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HoverTableDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011082

Comment: in 10.10 this method will not be called if you use source list

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Can you also post the swift equivalent of it?