# NSTableView changes highlighting style

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` with "Source List" highlighting on OS X 10.10.3. Usually the highlighting shows up as a blue background and white text as shown here:

[image: Highlighting style 1]

But occasionally (usually when dragging the app across windows) the highlighting style will suddenly switch to a greyish translucent background:

[image: Highlighting style 2]

A few times the tableview has even mixed the two, with the second highlight style being used when I change the selection, and a previous selected row using the first highlight style.

How can I make the table view only use the first highlighting style all the time?

Comment: I can suggest a workaround for your problem , you can extend the NSColor class and override secondarySelectedControlColor and return alternateSelectedControlColor value here.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work; categories can't actually override existing methods on classes. Also, this could have the side effect of changing the colour of a bunch of other controls too.

Comment: Yes. It's true . That should have the side effect . Otherwise you can subclass NSTableView override highlightSelectionInClipRect.Please take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662924/how-to-make-round-cornered-nstableview-rows